# find in which date product is uploaded in admin panel

Tags: date

we uploaded lot of products to magento site

we want to know in which date or month we uploaded the product.

is there any way we can get the information about product uploaded date.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the table `catalog_product_entity` there should be a field called `created_at`. that's the date when you added the product.

Comment: hi @marius, thanks boss, you are awesome as always....

Comment: for 1 product : 2015-06-02 ,

another product - 2015-02-06 

this is still may, why june month also dislaying?

Comment: I have no idea why you have those values. I just told you where to look.

Comment: i got it, for some products the month and day is swapped, strange but true.... thanks again....